# WSO2 ESB launch on error sequence when fault received

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to launch the on error sequence o generate a internal error when I receive a soap fault response in my orchestration. Something like throw an exception in Java.

An easy way is to set a filter in each sequence so that, when a fault tag is received, the onError sequence is launched. I guess there must be better ways to do this.

How can I make soap fault responses are treated like an error so that the on error sequence is launched?

Comment: I think the only possible method is to check with a filter as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not straight-forward until [WSO2 ESB 4.5.0](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/) (which is the latest release). There is new property introduced "FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" to get this done. See [this](http://maharachchi.blogspot.com/2012/09/now-you-can-send-soapfaults-to-fault.html) post for a sample configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In your proxy configuration, define the fault sequence..

Comment: It's already defined. I have an orchestration that requests for some data to a service to build the final request to be sent. What I want to do is to return a fault response when this services returns an error.